# Tabs in Chrome Browser shrink too much

Tags: google-chrome, browser

If I open up many tabs in Chrome, the Tabs start to shrink. This is usually a normal behavior if the tabs would use the whole availible space, BUT in my case the tabs shrink too much.
They don't use up the whole availible space anymore, but only go until somwhere at three quarters of the window. The more tabs I open, the larger the availible space gets until it reaches a maximum. This strikes me as somewhat not so normal.

Another funny thing is, if I use a second Monitor to extend my Desktop, Tabs will be smaller on the second Desktop and will only fill half the availible space from the beginning.
For example right now I have 6 tabs open, which fill out approximately half the availible space. If I open more tabs, only the tab size reduces. This has not been like that when I first installed the browser.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Is there any solution for this?

I hereby explicitly mean NO extensions. I found enough extensions to handle tabs. I just want them to behave normally without any of those tab-extensions. Re-Installing Chrome does NOT work, I tried that.

Comment: How about removing the current extension you have? Maybe one of them is doing that for you by accident.

Comment: I also had that suspicion, so I tried deactivating them without success. I will try to remove them completely later today.

Comment: Oh and one last thing you may be able to try, is reset browser setting. Chrome - Settings - Reset Browser Settings.

Comment: Just tried it, but the problem persists.

Comment: This is not under Windows 8.1 .. is it? [Google Forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/QZoQIbiawDs%5B1-25-true%5D) seems to show a few possible workaround. One is as Jay has mentioned "HiDPI Support", another is to change Windows scaling, and another is (unfortunately) to install a [Theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/monochrome/idnlphmmcijokifloflhecnkkhbpdnnk?hl=en).

Comment: It now is Windows 8.1. But the problem was already there before the update. HiDPI does not work for me, as you can see in the link I posted in a comment on the answer below. I had a theme and I removed it, because I thought, this might me causing it, but it didn't. I will now google this Windows scaling stuff, you mentioned and I will also follow the google forum thread. I didn't find that before, thanks.

Comment: I found a solution in the google forum, that worked for me. I checked "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays" in Control Panel\Appearance and Personalisation\Display and then chose the 100% scaling. Now the empty tab space is history.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this on my Lenovo Z50 Win 8.1 by setting the Chrome - Windows shortcut property setting **> Compatibility > Disable display scaling on high DPI settings** Chrome tabs are correct now

Answer (score 0):

Well this is really strange. The tabs should shrink more and more if you have multiple tabs opened and if you close those tabs it should revert back to its default state.

Re-installing the browser 'may' fix this problem but, try pinning the tabs of your chrome. By using the "Pin Tab" option.

OR

You can change the font size, maybe your font size is unbearably small, Or try messing with the zoom. By going to settings and then Zoom.

Go to Control Panel, Appearance and Personalization, Fonts, Change Font Size. "Change the size of all items"

There is another method:

1. Open a new tab, type chrome://flags into the URL bar, and hit enter.
2. Find the entry for 'HiDPI Support' and change the drop down box from 'Default' to 'Enabled'.

Comment: As mentioned, re-installing did not fix the problem. Also, pinning the tabs, playing with the zoom and changing the font size had no effect right now.

Comment: Please try this method: There is another method:

1) Open a new tab, type chrome://flags into the URL bar, and hit enter. 2) Find the entry for 'HiDPI Support' and change the drop down box from 'Default' to 'Enabled'.

Comment: This really messed up the browser. Tabs weren't visible anymore, scrollbar and address bar were gone and the cursor didn't click where it was supposed to. The only way to successfully navigate was with the keyboard.

Comment: Revert it back to Defaults then. What is your screen resolution and what do you use ? Plus, It will not "mess up" the browser you just need to Check "HiDPI Support" Pick From default to Enable and Restart your Chrome.

Comment: My screen resolution is 1920x1080. I use Windows 8.1 on a lenovo ideapad Y580 with a Geforce GTX 660M graphics card. This is what I mean with "messing": http://image-upload.de/image/Cp2ciV/596b6e7b47.png Also I use a german version of Chrome, version 32.0.1700.76 m, if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome version 88 or later, go to `chrome://flags` and search for **Scrollable Tabstrip**, choose any *Enabled* options, and restart the browser.

More details: [Chrome is making it even easier to manage your endless tabs](https://bgr.com/tech/google-chrome-tab-groups-scrollable-custom-size/)